# L.GPX is not a constructor

Tags: leaflet, gpx

i'm looking for import GPX file inside my Leaflet map
but when i try the site it respond with L.GPX is not a constructor
i only have that in my head

```
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
```

and that inside body

```
<div id="map"></div>

<script>    
    var sites = {!! json_encode($markers) !!};

    var map = L.map('map').setView([{{ config('leaflet.map_center_latitude') }}, {{ config('leaflet.map_center_longitude') }}], {{ config('leaflet.zoom_level') }});
    
    L.tileLayer('https://api.maptiler.com/maps/streets/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x.png?key=2Qw6dd02HLfOXS3LDGMP', {
        attribution: '<a href="https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/" target="_blank">&copy; MapTiler</a> <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank">&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors</a>'
    }).addTo(map);

    var marker;
    sites.forEach(element => {
        marker = L.marker([element[0], element[1]]).addTo(map);
    });

    var gpx = '/resources/gpx/pont.gpx'; // URL to your GPX file or the GPX itself
    
    new L.GPX(gpx, {
        async: true,
        polyline_options: {
              color: '#ff0000',
              }
        }
    ).on('loaded', function(e) {
        map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
    }).addTo(map);

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to [load the plugin before you can use it](https://github.com/mpetazzoni/leaflet-gpx#usage):

> **Usage**
> First, include the Leaflet.js and Leaflet-GPX scripts in your HTML
> page:

As described, add the following line, in your header or before your script

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet-gpx/1.4.0/gpx.min.js"></script>
```